# Hourly warning message in postfix log

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have logcheck set up to send me hourly updates of my logfiles, and for the past two days I get this entry once every hour in my /var/log/mail.warn:

```
Nov 17 12:36:02 mailserv postfix/smtpd[4114]: warning: hostname secure.sitesdns.com does not resolve to address 77.92.66.3: Name or service not known
```

So I tried to find out more about what's happeneing here, and found this corresponding lines in /var/log/mail.info:

```
Nov 17 12:36:02 mailserv postfix/postscreen[6112]: CONNECT from [77.92.66.3]:43778 to [my IP]:25
Nov 17 12:36:02 mailserv postfix/postscreen[6112]: PASS OLD [77.92.66.3]:43778
Nov 17 12:36:02 mailserv postfix/smtpd[6117]: warning: hostname secure.sitesdns.com does not resolve to address 77.92.66.3: Name or service not known
Nov 17 12:36:02 mailserv postfix/smtpd[6117]: connect from unknown[77.92.66.3]
Nov 17 12:36:02 mailserv postfix/smtpd[6117]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[77.92.66.3]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname
Nov 17 12:36:02 mailserv postfix/smtpd[6117]: disconnect from unknown[77.92.66.3]
```

I didn't fully get all of what's happening here, but the "PASS OLD" means that it's temporarily whitelisted by Postfix's postscreen, so I went to find the first instance, which was two days ago:

```
Nov 15 03:17:12 mailserv postfix/postscreen[4486]: CONNECT from [77.92.66.3]:41907 to [my IP]:25
Nov 15 03:17:18 mailserv postfix/postscreen[4486]: PASS NEW [77.92.66.3]:41907
Nov 15 03:17:18 mailserv postfix/smtpd[4491]: warning: hostname secure.sitesdns.com does not resolve to address 77.92.66.3: Name or service not known
Nov 15 03:17:18 mailserv postfix/smtpd[4491]: connect from unknown[77.92.66.3]
Nov 15 03:17:18 mailserv postfix/smtpd[4491]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[77.92.66.3]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname
Nov 15 03:17:18 mailserv postfix/smtpd[4491]: disconnect from unknown[77.92.66.3]
```

Since then, this entry appears roughly every 70 minutes.

Obviously, I'm not the first to get this log entry, so I've tried to Google for solutions - but most of the time it just indicates that my own hostname is not resolved to my own IP. But this is not the issue here. I'm just wondering if my server is compromised in any way.

Regarding mail server settings, it's a Debian 8.5 server with all settings exactly as described in this guide (guide is in German but all the settings can be found there):

https://thomas-leister.de/sicherer-mailserver-dovecot-postfix-virtuellen-benutzern-mysql-ubuntu-server-xenial/

Any help appreciated - even if it's just explaining what exactly those things mean, as I'm not even exactly sure what's happening there.

Comment: It's not your fault. The DNS lookup for secure.sitesdns.com doesn't map to 77.92.66.3, the reverse DNS lookup works just fine. Their DNS settings are not correct. Your postfix doesn't do anything wrong.

Comment: Oh... okay, thanks @Lenniey. Is there anything I can do to suppress this specific warning, as I get an hourly mail because of this (but I don't want to turn logcheck off for mail.warn as it sometimes might give me actually useful warnings)?

Comment: Well I don't use logcheck, but you can try to alter its "expressions" database to ignore said warning, maybe?